# How to call several controls when creating tabs dinamically

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am creating tabs dinamically and i am using the same fxml file for all of them. So, all type of controls that I've included has de same "fx:id". I use this: "@FXML TextField textField". How could I use the TextField of the second tab, the TextField of the first tab, etc?

```
@Controller
public class MascotaTabControllerImpl implements MascotaTabController
{

private AnchorPane anchorPane;
private Tab tab;

private Mascota mascota;

@FXML
private ComboBox<String> comboMascota;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> comboTamano;
@FXML
private TextField fieldNombreMascota;
@FXML
private RadioButton radioAlergiaSi;
@FXML
private RadioButton radioAlergiaNo;
@FXML
private TextField fieldRaza;
@FXML
private TextField fieldPeso;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> comboSexo;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> comboAgresividad;
@FXML
private TextArea areaObservaciones;
@FXML
private Button buttonEditar;
@FXML
private Button buttonCancelar;


@Override
public void inicializacionFxmlFile(TabPane tabPane, Collection<Mascota> mascotas)
{
    try
    {

        for(Mascota mascota : mascotas)
        {
            anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/mascotaTab.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            anchorPane.getChildren().setAll(loader.load());

            tab = new Tab();
            tab.setContent(anchorPane);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

            tab.setText(mascota.getNombre());
            fieldNombreMascota.setText(mascota.getNombre());
            fieldRaza.setText(mascota.getRaza());
            comboSexo.setValue(mascota.getSexo());
            fieldPeso.setText(String.valueOf(mascota.getPeso()));
            comboTamano.setValue(mascota.getTamano());
            comboAgresividad.setValue(mascota.getAgresividad());
            areaObservaciones.setText(mascota.getObservaciones());

            mascota.setNombre(fieldNombreMascota.getText());    

        }

        tabSelected(tabPane, mascotas);

        buttonEditar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                  {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {       
                mascota.setNombre(fieldNombreMascota.getText());
                mascota.setRaza(fieldRaza.getText());
                mascota.setSexo(comboSexo.getValue());
                mascota.setPeso(Float.parseFloat(fieldPeso.getText()));
                mascota.setTamano(comboTamano.getValue());
                mascota.setAgresividad(comboAgresividad.getValue());
                mascota.setObservaciones(areaObservaciones.getText());
                clienteService.actualizarMascota(mascota);;
            }
      });

        buttonCancelar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                  {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                return;
            }
      });

    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Edit: imagine "for" statement runs twice. How could call controls (TextFields, ComboBoxes, etc.) of the first tab?

For example, when "for" statement runs the first time "fieldNombreMascota" reference is "id=110" but when "for" statement runs the second time, the same TextField reference is "id=113". So how can I call them with annotation @FXML?

Comment: Each time you load the FXML file, you should get a different controller instance. So each controller will relate to just one set of controls (i.e. one tab). It is hard to tell what you mean without some code: can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (do not post you entire project...).

Comment: You are using the same object as a controller every time you load the FXML file, because you call `loader.setController(this)`. When you do that, the `FXMLLoader` will set the values of the `@FXML`-injected fields each time, so it will overwrite them each time. Don't do that: you need a different object each time you load the FXML. (Also, it looks like you are using the same controller class for different FXML files. Don't do that either: each FXML file should have its own Controller class, and you should let the `FXMLLoader` create a different instance each time you call `load`.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you call

```
loader.setController(this);
```

inside your loop, every time you call `loader.load()` you will reuse the same object as the controller for the FXML you are loading. This means each time you go through that `for` loop, the `@FXML`-injected fields will get redefined. So by doing this, you essentially make it impossible to access any FXML fields except the ones from the last iteration of the loop.

You ***must not call*** `loader.setController(this)`. The "standard" way to combine FXML files and controllers is to use an `fx:controller` attribute in the root element of the FXML file, specifying a class name. This will cause the `FXMLLoader` to create a new instance of that class every time you call `loader.load()`. If there is some other problem you are trying to solve by attempting the non-standard way you are doing things, then the solution you are attempting is not the right approach.

If you organize your code well, the FXML creates a controller instance, and there should be no need whatsoever to access that controller externally. You may need some of your controllers to access a shared data model of some kind, but this is certainly not the right approach to achieve that.